# Complex values using FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following system of equations:

```
A = Max[2, y/x];

f1 = x^(0.1)  + y^(-2.2324);
f2 = x^2 * y^A + y^(-3) - 3;

FindRoot[{f1 , f2 }, {{x, -10}, {y, 0.1}}, MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

I get the following output:

[image: Output from FindRoot]

As you can see, the fact that FindRoot looks also for complex values implies that it is impossible to evaluate the function `Max`. How can I tell FindRoot to look only at real values?

Comment: Your starting value of `x = -10` makes `x^0.1` complex-valued.  You need to keep `x` and `y` greater than or equal to zero. E.g. `{{x, 1, 0, 100}, {y, 0.1, 0, 100}}`.  See the docs for `FindRoot` for the various argument forms.

Comment: The equation `f1 == 0` has no real solutions.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelE2. I was about to ask you something related to that. Does the fact that FindRoot evaluates complex values imply that there are no real solutions? That is, does the algorithm stops when it has to face an "invalid comparison"?

Comment: `FindRoot` computes complex values simply because it plugs i `x = -10` and `(-10)^0.1` is complex, which in turn leads to an increment for `x, y` that is complex. Then you get the invalid comparison error and `f2` does not evaluate to a number. -- There are no real solutions because for `f1` to be real we need `x >= 0` and `y > 0`; in such a case `f1` is positive and cannot be zero.

Comment: Thank! I would grateful if you can clarify this one more thing. Can I say that if FindRoot evaluates complex values of the unknowns is either because I specified the starting values so that it is forced to so, **or** FindRoot did not find **real** solutions and, therefore, tries with complex solution?

Comment: If it does not find a real solution, you will get some other error. Here are three distinct cases: `FindRoot[Exp[x], {x, 1}]`, `FindRoot[1 + x^2, {x, 1}]`, `FindRoot[1 + x^2 + Sin[1/x], {x, 1}]`.  It won't look for complex roots if the function values stay real and the initial values are real.  (To get complex roots in the last two examples, you have to give a complex starting point like `{x, 1 + I}`.)

Comment: Very clear. Thank you very much. You really helped me.

Comment: Your invalid comparison error evidently comes from your `Max` function in comparing 2 with a complex number.  `Max[2, I]` gives the same error.   Given your current definition of `A`, I don't see that searching for complex roots would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Note: The OP posted [a question in Meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2367/what-should-i-do-if-somebody-answers-my-question-in-the-comment), asking what to do about accepting, since my answer was in the comments.  I thought this was so considerate, that it motivated me to oblige the OP and post my comment as an answer, even if the community judges that the underlying facts about `Power` and `FindRoot` are easily found in the documentation.]*

`FindRoot` computes complex values because it plugs in the initial value `x = -10` and `x^0.1` becomes `(-10)^0.1`, which is complex. This in turn leads to an increment for `x`, `y` that is complex. Then you get the invalid comparison error from `Max` in `f2`, and `f2` does not evaluate to a number.  Hence the error from `FindRoot`.

There are no real solutions to `f1 == 0` because for `f1` to be real we need `x >= 0` and `y > 0`; in such a case `f1` is positive and cannot be zero.

The docs for [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) state:

> If all equations and starting values are real, then `FindRoot` will search only for real roots. If any are complex, it will also search for complex roots.
>   ...
>   When the function is complex for real input, a real starting value may give a complex result...

(These can be found by searching the doc page for "complex," e.g., by using <kbd>cmd</kbd>-F on a Mac.)

Answer (score 1):

As an example, this works, but I don't know what answer you want.
Choose `A`, either `2` or `y/x`

```
A = 2

f1 = x^(0.1) + y^(-2.2324)
f2 = x^2*y^A + y^(-3) - 3

fr = FindRoot[{f1, f2}, {{x, 1 + .01 I}, {y, 0.1 + .1 I}}]
(*{x -> -0.262288 + 1.99821 I, y -> 0.230107 + 0.94138 I}*)

 y/x /. %
(*0.448272 - 0.173997 I)
```

So `A = 2` is larger than the real part of `y/x`, so stick with that.

Check the solution

```
f1 /. fr
(*2.22045*10^-16 - 1.45717*10^-16 I*)

f2 /. fr
(*0. + 2.22045*10^-16 I*)
```

Both equations are essentially zero to machine precision.  I was not able to get a solution with your initial guesses for x and y even adding an imaginary component.